# How do I fix an MS visual studio package install error? Version 16.3.9

Tags: c#

Error message.
Package 'gtmetrix-net 1.0.2' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, please check this article about asking questions here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask then edit your question by adding details.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned package only works with `.NET Framework 4`.

In order to use it, your need migrate you project from `.NET Core 3` to `.NET Framework 4`.